# Using Laravel 5 with AngularJS blade tag conflict

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I am trying to setup Angular with Laravel 5.

I have tried doing in appServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Blade::setRawTags("[[", "]]");
    \Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>'); // for variables and all things Blade
    \Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>'); // for escaped data
}
```

With:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <h1>Hello, {{ yourName }}!</h1>
</div>
```

But I'm getting:

```
Use of undefined constant yourName - assumed 'yourName'...
```

Comment: What do you get if you call `\Blade::getTags()` in your controller?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Call to protected method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::getTags() from context 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade'

Comment: Whooops. Try `\Blade::getContentTags()`

Comment: @lukasgeiter I get ["<%","%>"]

Comment: Weird... That means setting the tags actually worked. Have you tried emptying the view cache? (delete all view compiled views in `storage/framework/views`)

Comment: It's got rid of the error but now my script tag is out as plain text: <script async="async" data-main="js/main.js" src="http://mbms.com/js/requirejs.js"></script>

Comment: And how are you generating the script tag? with `[[ ... ]]`?

Comment: With <% and %> as defined in my appServiceProvider

Comment: Those are the content tags. They will be escaped. You have to use the raw tags. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28388283/1903366) for a short description of the three different tags

Comment: Using [[]] has worked, but my Angular JS isn't working, maybe I'll drop that in another question.

Comment: If you think it has nothing to do with the tag issue then ask a new question yes.. In the meantime I'll properly answer this one ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing changes that have to do with Blade (Extending Blade, changing the tags etc) always make sure to delete the cached views.

They're located in `storage/framework/views`.

Just delete all files (except the `.gitignore`)

If you want something a bit more practical you can create a command to do that. Like [this one](https://gist.github.com/lucasmichot/7313220)

Answer (score 47):

The easiest way to do this is to simply use @ in front of your Angular code:

```
 <div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <h1>Hello, @{{ yourName }}!</h1>
</div>
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: If you're using Laravel >= 5.3 Homestead you'll need to disable Vue for the Angular tags to work correctly, as well as use the @ symbol. With Vue enabled simple tags will work, but no variable resolution or model updates in tags.

Answer (score 4):

#### Laravel >= 5.3

While adding @ in front of the braces does still work, Laravel has also included another handy blade utility that lets you mark an entire block as-is:

```
@verbatim
<div>
    {{ ctl.variable1 }}
    {{ ctl.variable2 }}
</div>
@endverbatim
```

Particularly helpful if you're not doing much with the Blade template rendering

Answer (score 0):

Else you modify angular syntax...

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```