# Which method is good to use for laravel 5 and angularjs tag conflict?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I had print value issue in laravel view, i was trying to print `$scope` value inside laravel blade. I searched about and find two kind of solution.

**1- Change angularjs print tag**

By this [**method**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) i can change angularjs print tag.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    });

    app.controller('app', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.text_print = 'this is text';
    });
```

Now in blade i can print like `<% text_print %>`

**2- Add `@` for printing angularjs `$scope` value**

I found an up-voted [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548694/using-laravel-5-with-angularjs-blade-tag-conflict) in which @Paul A.T. Wilson says that

> The easiest way to do this is to simply use @ in front of your Angular code

Example `@{{text_print}}`

Both are working for me, actually i want to make a plugin, so which method should i use? because i'm not sure the second one is compatible with laravel old version. I want my plugin compatible with all version of laravel.

Can anyone guide me about this, i would like to appreciate. Thank You

Comment: Do you want to make a php plugin or an angularJs plugin?

Comment: @atefth i want to make plugin for laravel, so i will use both php (laravel stuff) and angularjs.

Answer (score 2):

> Changing either interpolation strings for Blade or angular is the best option if you want your plugin to work with older versions of Laravel.

- For angularJs you already know how to do it from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider).
- For Blade, inside your Laravel app's AppServiceProvider.php file add the following code in the boot function:

  ```
  public function boot() {
    Blade::setRawTags("[[", "]]");
    // for variables and Blade
    Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');
    // for escaped data
    Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');
  }
  ```

**Note:** In my opinion it's easier to change the interpolation tags for angular as changing the interpolation tags for blade requires you to ***clear out*** the `storage/framework/views` folder.

> Apparently there's another way to do this, but I'm not sure if it will work in older versions:

```
@verbatim
<div>
  {{ variableOne }}
  {{ variableTwo }}
</div>
@endverbatim
```

The verbatim annotation indicates that the section is **as-is**, ie: Blade will leave it out.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge +1

Comment: @Mr.Developer do let me know if the verbatim annotations work out for you.