# Laravel 5.4 with angular variable error

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to use Angular 1.6 in Laravel blade it raise exception.
I have tried [this link](http://laraveldaily.com/ways-solve-angular-blade-conflict/) to solve and many other answer I have tried but non of these worked for me.
here is code

```
<div class="row" ng-app="CalculatorApp" ng-controller="CalculatorController">
    <p>Profit Before {{ var }} </p>
</div>
```

here is Js co

```
angular.module('CalculatorApp', []).controller('CalculatorController', 
 function($scope) {
 $scope.var=0;
    });
```

here is error/exception

```
use of undefined constant var - assumed 'var'
```

Comment: Don't use "var" it is a reserved word in javascript, declares a variable.

Comment: @axel.michel I have another name in my js. just to be on point/error I have changed it. for more understandable

Comment: Rename the variable name of var and check

Comment: Change var to any other name and check

Comment: Already checked?

Comment: @RajaMohamed I have another name in js.

Comment: Is this error in laravel or in angular ?

Comment: @user2486 I have used a other name in JS. just to on point i have changed it.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani which are your actual Blade content tags?

Comment: @user2486 page is not being load. It just show Laravel exception.
use of undefined constant var - assumed 'myVar'

Comment: @axel.michel \my blade tag is same as angular tag.
I have checked my code without blade eg .html file it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

1) I changed library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

2) changed code Putted after body start.

```
    <body>
    var custom = angular.module('CalculatorApp', []);
custom.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
custom.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope) {
    $scope.aa=0;

    });
```

html .

```
<div class="row" ng-app="CalculatorApp" ng-controller="CalculatorController">
        [[ aa ]]
     </div>
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to solve this problem.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Both Laravel and Angular use the double curly brackets per default, this is causing your error:

**in Blade you can mark a complete block as string:**

```
@verbatim
<div class="row" ng-app="CalculatorApp" ng-controller="CalculatorController">
    <p>Profit Before {{ var }} </p>
</div>
@endverbatim
```

**Or your angular:**

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

In this case all your angular template code has to use something like `<%var%>`

Comment: Might be the blade cache? - have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548694/using-laravel-5-with-angularjs-blade-tag-conflict, could be helpful.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani be aware that you just change one of both (either angular or blade, if you change both, you reproduce the error. Or try the blade option "entire block as-is" (see updated answer).

Comment: sir I have checked these individually. expect Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');  when i use this is show an other error.
may be I'm not putting the code in right place.
Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::setContentTags()

Comment: sir can you please tell me where should I put this  `Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');` code. may be because of this . I'm facing error.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani I just checked the issues board at lavarel, seems that the team deleted that option: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17736 - no way to do this any longer, you'll need to escape the complete block, or using @{{xxx}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152852/discussion-between-mahmood-sanjrani-and-axel-michel).

Answer (score 1):

Use `@` to escape blade processsing angular interpolation.

```
<div class="row" ng-app="CalculatorApp" ng-controller="CalculatorController">
    <p>Profit Before @{{ var }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: sir I have used it . as I have Link/url/href in my Question. but it only print the value including {{}} .

Comment: did u change template tags for angular or laravel? u also need to check if you've bootstrapped angular

Comment: sir I'm using bootstrap and I have included Angular external link. I  tried to change blade tags and angular tags ,, but none to these are working for me. :(

Comment: can you tell me where should I change blade tag. may be I'm putting code in wrong file.\

Answer (score 0):

Var is keyword in JavaScript , I hope rename the variable name enough to fix.

Comment: Check my comment on question

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is also using same template tags so its check for laravel variable. change for angular like this

```
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[{');
 $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('CalculatorApp', [$scope]).controller('CalculatorController', function($scope) { $scope.var1=0; });
```

Check this out.

Comment: $scope.var1=0; ?

sir I have told you there is not issue of variable name. I have other name in my JS function.

Comment: Find another change there inside [$scope]