# display json data that contains html

Tags: html, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following json

```
[{
  "date": "2011",
  "content": "<p>Hello world?</p>"
},
{
  "date": "2012",
  "content": "<p><strong>Hello again</strong></p>"
}]
```

my controller has

```
public function index() {
  $data['json'] = json_decode(file_get_contents('location_of_json_file.json'));
  return view('index', $data);
}
```

my view has

```
@foreach ($json as $a)
  {{ $a->content }}
@endforeach
```

but what i get is

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello world?&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Hello again&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

how can i make it parse the html code instead of displaying the syntax? i've tried `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`. i tried to `json_encode` in different place of the code, i'm lost. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5, by default `{{ ... }}` will escape the output using `htmlentities`. To output raw HTML that get's interpreted use `{!! ... !!}`:

```
@foreach ($json as $a)
    {!! $a->content !!}
@endforeach
```

[Here's a comparison between the different echo brackets and how to change them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28388283/1903366)

Answer (score 1):

The Blade output tags changed between Laravel 4 and Laravel 5.  You're looking for:

```
{!! $a->content !!}
```

In Laravel 4, `{{ $data }}` would echo data as is, whereas `{{{ $data }}}` would echo data after running it through htmlentities.

However, Laravel 5 has changed it so that `{{ $data }}` will echo data after running it through htmlentities, and the new syntax `{!! $data !!}` will echo data as is.

Documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures).